# How get Image Url by product_id or other way

Tags: product, url, image, get

I am rendering `sales_items` rows in frontend
Screenshot is: 
[image]

Can anyone please help me to find how get image path here from product id or any other solution. and set path in `src` tag ?

My **.phtml file** code is there :

```
<?php
$OrderItemHelper = $this->helper('CompanyName\ModuleName\Helper\Orders');
$collection = $OrderItemHelper->getOrderItem();
?>
<b><i>Total order Items <?php echo count($collection)?></i></b>
<hr>
<table class="data table" id="test-data-table">
    <caption class="table-caption">Seller Product Data</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="col title">ID</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col title">Product Id</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col title">Image</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Sku</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Description</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Sale Date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Price</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Total</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col author">Action</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($collection as $key => $data): ?>
        <tr>
            <td data-th="ID" ><?php echo $data->getItemId(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="ID" ><?php echo $data->getProductId(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Image" ><img src="how can get path here" ></td>
            <td data-th="Name" ><?php echo $data->getName(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Sku"><?php echo $data->getSku(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Description"><?php echo $data->getDescription(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="CreatedAt"><?php echo $data->getCreatedAt(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Price"><?php echo $data->getPrice(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Sku"><?php echo $data->getQtyOrdered(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Sku"><?php echo ($data->getQtyOrdered()*$data->getPrice()); ?></td>

            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'admin/catalog/product/edit/id/'.$data->getId(); ?>" class="action view">
                    <span>View</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>    

<?php
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you load product using product id like

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($data->getProductId());
```

After that, get the URL of the image

```
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();
```

You set on this URL in your code like

```
<td data-th="Image" ><img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" ></td>
```

Comment: let me check please

Comment: Yes Thank You is absolute work ! 
before your answer i was going to try get path from db use Join between catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value and catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table .
i.e catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.entity_id=catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value_id .